# Function with inflection points

Tags: calculus

*Question:* Let $g_a$ be the function given by $g_a(x)=(x^2-a)\cdot e^x$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

For which values of $a$ does the graph of $g_a$ have one or more inflection points?

---

The second derivative is given by $$g_a''(x)=(x^2+4x+2-a)\cdot e^x$$
Now in order for $g_a$ to have one or more inflection points $g_a'$ needs to change sign and $g''_a$ needs to have one or more zero(s). Using the discriminant, we find:
$$4+4a>0$$ (since $g'_a$ needs to change sign, and therefore needs to have exactly two zeros) and
$$8+4a\geq 0$$
(since $g''_a$ needs to have one or two zero(s))

The intersection of those two equalities gives $\boxed{a>-1}$.

The answer in the answer book is $a>-2$. Apparently there is a hole in my understanding of this, where is my mistake?

Comment: Where do you get $4+4a$ from?

Comment: It's rather $g''_a$ that has to change sign.

Comment: $g'$ *needs not* to change sign. $g''$ does.

Comment: In this case $g_{-2}''(x)=(x+2)^2\cdot e^x\geq0$ which does *not* change sign...

Comment: Here is an answer:$g_a''$ changes sign iff the (reduced) discriminant $\Delta'=2^2-1\times (2-a)=2+a>0$ giving $a>-2$. That's it:) @rae306

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$$g_a''(x)=(x^2+4x+2-a)\cdot e^x$$
we get that inflections points do exist if and only if the related discrimant is $>0$:
$$
\Delta'=2^2-1\times (2-a)=2+a>0,
$$ that is

> $$
> a>-2
> $$

as announced in the book.

Comment: Thanks, I should have known that :)

Comment: You are welcome.